# Receiving a wrong output from \ref when \ContinuedFloat is involved

Tags: cross-referencing, captions, labels, ref

I get my custom numbering scheme in captions in the following form:

- **Figure A.1.5**
- the "5" is the chapter counter,
- the "1" is the figure counter,
- and the "A" is the counter for the `ContinuedFloat`.

  ```
   \documentclass[12pt]{book}
   \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
   \usepackage{cleveref}
   \usepackage{graphicx}

   \usepackage{caption}

   \captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=small}

   \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\thechapter}  

   \renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\Alph{ContinuedFloat}.}

   \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{MyFormat}{#1 \theContinuedFloat \arabic{figure}.\thechapter}
   \captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=MyFormat}


   \begin{document}
   \setcounter{chapter}{4}
   \chapter{Chapter five}
   \section{Section one}
   \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \ContinuedFloat*
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
   \caption{This is my caption}
   \label{fig:A:1:5}
   \end{figure}

   \begin{figure}[!ht]
   \ContinuedFloat
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
   \caption{This is my caption}
   \label{fig:B:1:5}
   \end{figure}

   we have in \ref{fig:A:1:5} that \ref{fig:B:1:5}
   \end{document}
  ```

[image]

When I reference the same ones through the command of `\ref`, I weirdly get "1.5A." instead of "A.1.5".

*I don't want to use `subcaption` package.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The manual of the `caption` package states that (emphasis mine):

> If you would like to use the ContinuedFloat counter for the
> references, too, you could redefine the command \theContinuedFloat
> instead, which will be **appended to** the figure or table counter
> automatically in continued floats and is preset to be empty.

So, the ContinuedFloat counter is appended, i.e., added at the end, of the counter for referencing purposes, resulting in the `1.5A.` behavior that you have noticed.

You can change this by redefining the command in the `caption` package that implements this behavior. Instead of putting the ContinuedFloat counter at the end you can put it at the beginning, so the reference format will match your own CaptionLabelFormat. The source is found in `caption.sty` at about 1/3 of the code. In the MWE below the line causing the issue is commented out and a new line is added below that to implement the reverse order.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\caption@@@@continuedfloat[1]{%
  \caption@setoptions{ContinuedFloat}% for compatibility reasons
  \caption@setoptions{continuedfloat}%
  \caption@setoptions{continued#1}%
  %\expandafter\l@addto@macro\csname the#1\endcsname\thecontinuedfloat
  \expandafter\def\csname the#1\endcsname{\Alph{ContinuedFloat}.\arabic{#1}.\thechapter}
  \@ifundefined{theH#1}{}{%
    \expandafter\l@addto@macro\csname theH#1\endcsname{%
      \@alph\c@continuedfloat}}%
  \let\caption@@@@continuedfloat\@gobble}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=small}

\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\thechapter}  

\renewcommand\theContinuedFloat{\Alph{ContinuedFloat}.}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{MyFormat}{#1 \theContinuedFloat \arabic{figure}.\thechapter}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=MyFormat}


\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\chapter{Chapter five}
\section{Section one}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat*
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:A:1:5}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:B:1:5}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\fbox{non-continued figure}
\caption{some figure}
\label{somefig}
\end{figure}

we have in \ref{fig:A:1:5} that \ref{fig:B:1:5}

regular figure: \ref{somefig}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is a very time saving answer! Thank you!

Comment: This could be done without patching internal macros of the `caption` package. See my answer.

Comment: BTW: Should I have posted my suggested code change as comment instead, so Marijn could change her/his answer? I'm not familiar yet with tex.stackexchange.com, so I don't know if my behaviour (posting an improvement to an existing answer as new answer) was correct.

Comment: @P.M. no, you did the right thing - your approach is sufficiently different from mine (and much easier!) that it deserves a separate answer.

Comment: @Marijn I just have put your changed code line of `\caption@@@@continuedfloat` into a `\DeclareCaptionOption`, nothing more, so I'm still not sure if this deserves a separate answer. (And I removed the superfluous custom label format, but it is superfluous in your answer, too.) And the main question for me is not if anything deserves a separate answer, but what would be best for the questioner and user? When patching internal commands there is a chance that the solution will not work anymore with the upcoming version, so maybe it's better to edit your answer instead?!?

Comment: @P.M. there are currently three different answers to the question, each with a somewhat different approach (patching, alternative `\label`, or using a package command). All three of them work, so that is a good thing :) The current user, and also future visitors, can look at all three answers and decide which is the best for them at that time. If it turns out that the patch given in my answer is incompatible with a future version then they will choose one of the other two approaches. That is how StackExchange is supposed to work I think, so no need for edits I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

Answer code taken from Marijn but modified so only documented features of the `caption` package are used. This one does not redefine `\theContinuedFloat` but declares an option instead to modify `\thefigure` for continued floats:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=small}

\renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\thechapter}

\DeclareCaptionOption{continuedfigure}
  {\renewcommand\thefigure{\Alph{ContinuedFloat}.\arabic{figure}.\thechapter}}
\captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{continuedfigure=}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{4}
\chapter{Chapter five}
\section{Section one}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat*
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:A:1:5}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{fig:B:1:5}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering\fbox{non-continued figure}
\caption{some figure}
\label{somefig}
\end{figure}

we have in \ref{fig:A:1:5} that \ref{fig:B:1:5}

regular figure: \ref{somefig}
\end{document}
```

BTW: If `\thefigure` is modified this way there is no need for an own custom label format, so I dropped the `\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{myformat}{...}`.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, one can modify `\label` to store something other than `\thefigure`.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{book}
 \usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
 \usepackage{cleveref}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{caption}

 \captionsetup[figure]{font=small,labelfont=small}

 \renewcommand\thefigure{\arabic{figure}.\thechapter}  

 \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{MyFormat}{#1 \Alph{ContinuedFloat}.\thefigure}
 \captionsetup[ContinuedFloat]{labelformat=MyFormat}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}{\edef\@currentlabel{\Alph{ContinuedFloat}.\thefigure}\label}
\makeatother

 \begin{document}
 \setcounter{chapter}{4}
 \chapter{Chapter five}
 \section{Section one}
 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \ContinuedFloat*
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
 \caption{This is my caption}
 \mylabel{fig:A:1:5}
 
 \end{figure}

 \begin{figure}[!ht]
 \ContinuedFloat
 \centering
 \includegraphics[scale=.25]{example-image}
 \caption{This is my caption}
 \mylabel{fig:B:1:5}
 \end{figure}

 we have in \ref{fig:A:1:5} that \ref{fig:B:1:5}
 \end{document}
```